# Go 1.11 ignores the `vendor` directory, the errors give the impression the directory is never even looked at

Tags: go, gopath, govendor

I'm having the issue of Go 1.11.4 ignoring the `vendor` directory of the project I'm in.

When trying to run various commands, I get the following errors, even though the paths referenced are clearly present in the vendor directory.  The error message itself appears to indicate that the `vendor` directory is not even being looked at, at least not for this project that supposedly couldn't be found.

What exactly is going on, and how do I even troubleshoot this?

Below is a straight copy/paste from the terminal, after some `pbpaste | sed "s#…#R#g;s#…#M#g;s#…#D#g;s#…#B#g;s#…#example.org#g;s#^#`printf \t`#g" | pbcopy` script to anonymise the repositories.

```
ubuntu:R {607} go version
go version go1.11.4 linux/amd64
ubuntu:R {608} go build | & head -4
server.go:10:2: cannot find package "example.org/M/B" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/example.org/M/B (from $GOROOT)
    /home/ubuntu/go/src/example.org/M/B (from $GOPATH)
R.go:8:2: cannot find package "example.org/M/D" in any of:
ubuntu:R {609} ll vendor/example.org/M/B/
total 28
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  156 Jan 10 17:57 .drone.yml
8 -rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 6207 Jan 10 17:57 Gopkg.lock
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  798 Jan 10 17:57 Gopkg.toml
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   53 Jan 10 17:57 README.md
8 -rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4783 Jan 10 17:57 B.go
ubuntu:R {610} go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/ubuntu/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/ubuntu/go"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build981837178=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
ubuntu:R {611}
```

Comment: I filed an issue — https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29670

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Digging around, it appears that the `vendor` directory of the project you're working on is magically ignored if the project you're building is not under the `src` directory within `$GOPATH`, a requirement which makes absolutely zero sense whatsoever, especially for how difficult it is to troubleshoot this issue, and how unintuitive the whole concept is.

- One option is to create symlinks within the `src` in one of the `$GOPATH` directories back to the actual space on the disc where the project is checked out, and `cd` through the symlink to compile the project (e.g., `cd ~/go/src/R; go build`, or `pushd ~/go/src/R; go build; popd`).
- Another option is to start checkouts from scratch with the help of the tricks explained over at https://gist.github.com/dmitshur/6927554.

  ```
  git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://example.org/"
  go get example.org/M/R
  ```